# When opening the app through push notification, the inbox is cleared and not shown

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, android-app

Every morning, I have a push notification waiting, which is telling me about new inbox notifications.

I then tap on that notification and it opens the SE app. Previously, the app would directly display the inbox drawer and allow me to read my messages.

Lately, the app will open, my inbox will be marked as read and I just see my feed.

Comment: This is a really bad bug that I've seen too. I've been trying to track it down, I know *what*'s happening but so far I can't figure out *why* it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed as of 1.0.23. Let me know if you see it again.

Comment: Awesome. I'll check it out

Comment: It seems like the inbox is now always shown, but it's also fully marked as read. I believe that this only happens if the app wasn't running at all. When it is only woken up from sleep, the behavior is as expected (drawer shown, messages still unread).

Comment: Poke: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266007