# Achievements dialog fails to load achievements

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, achievements-dialog

The iOS fails to load the achievements for an hour or so. This happens on multiple devices.

The dialog presented:

> [image: Failed]

This doesn't seem to be network related since other parts of the app work as they should. And I can post this question...

Is this a bug? An outage on the API? Anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently released a [new privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260849/proposed-micro-privilege-site-analytics)... and in fine "we totally know what we're doing" fashion forgot to build out the Mobile and the API projects. Blame has been assigned and builds kicked off, so all issues should be resolved now.

Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: Indeed. It works now.