# Notifications from app never work

Tags: bug, android-app

When I click on the Android notification generated from the Stack Exchange app, it always brings up the Stack Exchange app, pulls a shade into view from the right side of the screen and displays nothing on it.

If I close the shade and open it again by clicking on the notifications button in the app, it opens up the shade and displays the notifications.

Usually I see the notification that was in the Android's notification shade, but not always.

I'm using Galaxy S4 with OS 4.3.

Comment: What is the app version? (There was [similar bug long ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225266/when-opening-the-app-through-push-notification-the-inbox-is-cleared-and-not-sho), that is already fixed)

Comment: Yes - mine has always done this as well, on every version including the latest, so my default process is to open the app, then close and open the shade.

Comment: Does this happen consistently? Do you know if it's only when the app hasn't been opened in a while, or even while it's already running? We've had some cold boot related errors with the notifications before (as linked above).

Comment: Was using 1.0.73 (171), just updated to 1.0.85 (183) which is the latest as of today and it seems to work now. Thanks.

Comment: I also get this - the play store is telling me I have the latest version (I signed up to beta-test the app).

Comment: Seems that if the comment is hidden because the thread is to long, that it will not open it up and highlight it. The SO notification will still have the notification highlighted. Clicking on the SO notification will bring up the question, but also not open up the comments.

Comment: I'm using the latest app (1.0.95) on a Galaxy S7 Edge running Android 7. When clicking on a given push notification, the app is started and the notification inbox is displayed. I would expect clicking on the notification to take me to the actual question, if not the specific comment, that is being notified. Why is it not designed to work this way?